Gagliardo diagram
Let $E_0,E_1$ a compatible couple of normed spaces. For every $x\in E_0+E_1$ we define the set $$\Gamma(x):=\{y=(y_0,y_1)\in\mathbb{R}^2: \exists(x_0,x_1)\in E_0\times E_1, x=x_0+x_1; ||x_i||_{E_i}\leq y_i, i=0,1\}.$$ I want to prove that for fixed $x$ this set is convex. Let $(y_0,y_1),(z_0,z_1)\in \Gamma(x)$. Since they are in the set there must exist $(x_0,x_1),(x_0',x_1')\in E_0\times E_1$ such as $$||x_i||\leq y_i,\,||x_i'||\leq z_i,\,i=0,1$$ so i have to prove that $(ty_0+(1-t)z_0,ty_1+(1-t)z_1)$ for $t\in (0,1)$ belongs to $\Gamma(x)$. I dont really know how to proceed, i think it must be straightforward if i can find a representation for $x$ involving $t$ in a convex way but i'm not able to find it. Any help will be very appreciated.

As you say let $(y_0,y_1), (z_0,z_1) \in \Gamma(x)$ and $(x_0,x_1), (x_0',x_1') \in E_0 \times E_1$ be points which realize
\begin{align}
   x_0 + x_1 = x, \ \|x_i\|_{E_i} \leq y_i \\
   x_0' + x_1' = x, \ \|x_i'\|_{E_i} \leq z_i \\
\end{align}
which must exist by the fact that $(y_0,y_1), (z_0,z_1) \in \Gamma(x)$.
We must show that for every $t \in (0,1)$ the point $(ty_0 + (1-t)z_0, ty_1 + (1-t)z_1) \in \Gamma(x)$.
This means for each $t$ you need to find a pair $(x_0^t,x_1^t)$ such that
$$x_0^t+x_1^t = x, \ \|x_i^t\|_{E_i} \leq ty_i + (1-t)z_i.$$
One such point is given by
$$x_i^t = tx_i + (1-t)x_i'$$
To see this observe that
\begin{align}
   x_0^t+x_1^t &= tx_0+(1-t)x_0' + tx_1+(1-t)x_1' \\
   &= t(x_0+x_1) + (1-t)(x_0' + x_1') \\
   &= tx + (1-t)x = x
\end{align}
while
\begin{align}
   \|x_i^t\|_{E_i} &= \|tx_i + (1-t)x_i'\|_{E_i} \\
   &\leq \|tx_i \|_{E_i} + \| (1-t)x_i'\|_{E_i} \\
   &= t\|x_i \|_{E_i} + (1-t)\| x_i'\|_{E_i} \\
   &\leq ty_i+(1-t)z_i
\end{align}
where we have used the sub-additivity of norms followed by their positive-homogeneity, and finally the properties of $x_i,x_i'$.
